# Do you want this question from meta.maths?

Tags: discussion, migration, allowed-questions

Over on meta.maths.SE this question was asked:

> [Teaching someone who doesn't put much effort in](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7158)

While certainly off-topic for meta.maths.SE, I think it's a reasonable and interesting question and might be suitable for academia.SE.  However, it's not apparent from the Academia [FAQ](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq) that it'd be on-topic.

> **Question**:  Should this question be migrated to academia.SE?

[**UPDATE**] This question has now been moved to:  [Teaching classmates who don't put much effort in](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/6170)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs some cleaning up, but there's a valid question buried in there. I think we could take the question, but it would have to be worked on a bit before we'd open it for response.

Comment: What kind of stuff would need to be changed?

Comment: The main issue is that the teaching aspect, rather than "group study" factor, would need to be emphasized. (The former is in keeping with the aim of the board; the latter is not.)